# How do I properly georeference variables in a netCDF CF-1.8 file?

Tags: qgis, netcdf, panoply

I am trying to write netCDF CF-1.8 compliant files with vector geometries corresponding to segments of a road network. The data are observations of aspects of vehicle flow within 15 minute time periods and so are described by two dimensions: segment ID and time interval. I want to be able to treat the data as time series attached to each segment similar to the typical examples given of weather stations but with geolocation provided by the vector geometries rather than simple lat/lon coordinates.

I have created a file using Python netCDF4 and cfgeom with CDL definition:

```
File "big_test.nc"
File type: Hierarchical Data Format, version 5
 
netcdf file:/Users/rogerdowning/Work/netcdf/big_test.nc {
  dimensions:
    instance = 1040;
    node = 2809;
    ts = 2880;
  variables:
    long geometry_container;
      :geometry_type = "line";
      :node_coordinates = "x y";
      :node_count = "node_count";
      :grid_mapping = "grid_mapping";
      :crs_wkt = "GEOGCRS[\"WGS 84\",ENSEMBLE[\"World Geodetic System 1984 ensemble\",MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (Transit)\"],MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G730)\"],MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G873)\"],MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G1150)\"],MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G1674)\"],MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G1762)\"],MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G2139)\"],ELLIPSOID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],ENSEMBLEACCURACY[2.0]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],CS[ellipsoidal,2],AXIS[\"geodetic latitude (Lat)\",north,ORDER[1],ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],AXIS[\"geodetic longitude (Lon)\",east,ORDER[2],ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],USAGE[SCOPE[\"Horizontal component of 3D system.\"],AREA[\"World.\"],BBOX[-90,-180,90,180]],ID[\"EPSG\",4326]]";
      :semi_major_axis = 6378137.0; // double
      :semi_minor_axis = 6356752.314245179; // double
      :inverse_flattening = 298.257223563; // double
      :reference_ellipsoid_name = "WGS 84";
      :longitude_of_prime_meridian = 0.0; // double
      :prime_meridian_name = "Greenwich";
      :geographic_crs_name = "WGS 84";
      :grid_mapping_name = "latitude_longitude";

    double x(node=2809);
      :standard_name = "longitude";
      :units = "degrees_east";
      :axis = "X";

    double y(node=2809);
      :standard_name = "latitude";
      :units = "degrees_north";
      :axis = "Y";

    long node_count(instance=1040);
      :long_name = "count of coordinates in each instance geometry";
      :units = "1";

    ubyte grid_mapping;
      :crs_wkt = "GEOGCRS[\"WGS 84\",ENSEMBLE[\"World Geodetic System 1984 ensemble\",MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (Transit)\"],MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G730)\"],MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G873)\"],MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G1150)\"],MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G1674)\"],MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G1762)\"],MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G2139)\"],ELLIPSOID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],ENSEMBLEACCURACY[2.0]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],CS[ellipsoidal,2],AXIS[\"geodetic latitude (Lat)\",north,ORDER[1],ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],AXIS[\"geodetic longitude (Lon)\",east,ORDER[2],ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],USAGE[SCOPE[\"Horizontal component of 3D system.\"],AREA[\"World.\"],BBOX[-90,-180,90,180]],ID[\"EPSG\",4326]]";
      :semi_major_axis = 6378137.0; // double
      :semi_minor_axis = 6356752.314245179; // double
      :inverse_flattening = 298.257223563; // double
      :reference_ellipsoid_name = "WGS 84";
      :longitude_of_prime_meridian = 0.0; // double
      :prime_meridian_name = "Greenwich";
      :geographic_crs_name = "WGS 84";
      :grid_mapping_name = "latitude_longitude";
      :horizontal_datum_name = "World Geodetic System 1984 ensemble";

    ulong ts(ts=2880);
      :units = "seconds since 1970-1-1 0:0:0";
      :calendar = "standard";
      :standard_name = "time";

    ulong segment(instance=1040);
      :geometry = "geometry_container";
      :grid_mapping = "grid_mapping";
      :units = "1";
      :long_name = "segment ID";
      :cf_role = "timeseries_id";

    ulong osm_id(instance=1040);
      :long_name = "OpenStreetMap ID associated with segment";
      :units = "1";
      :geometry = "geometry_container";
      :grid_mapping = "grid_mapping";

    String road_name(instance=1040);
      :long_name = "Road name for segment drawn from OSM";
      :units = "1";
      :geometry = "geometry_container";
      :grid_mapping = "grid_mapping";

    float avg_speed(instance=1040, ts=2880);
      :long_name = "Arithmetic mean of observed speeds over time period";
      :units = "mph";
      :geometry = "geometry_container";
      :grid_mapping = "grid_mapping";
      :coordinates = "segment ts";

    ubyte vehicle_density(instance=1040, ts=2880);
      :long_name = "Count of observed vehicles";
      :units = "1";
      :geometry = "geometry_container";
      :grid_mapping = "grid_mapping";
      :coordinates = "segment ts";

    float stationary(instance=1040, ts=2880);
      :long_name = "Average stationary time per vehicle";
      :units = "s";
      :geometry = "geometry_container";
      :grid_mapping = "grid_mapping";
      :coordinates = "segment ts";

    ubyte hard_brake(instance=1040, ts=2880);
      :units = "1";
      :long_name = "Count of hard braking events";
      :geometry = "geometry_container";
      :grid_mapping = "grid_mapping";
      :coordinates = "segment ts";

    ubyte hard_accel(instance=1040, ts=2880);
      :long_name = "Count of hard acceleration events";
      :units = "1";
      :geometry = "geometry_container";
      :grid_mapping = "grid_mapping";
      :coordinates = "segment ts";

  // global attributes:
  :featureType = "timeSeries";
  :Conventions = "CF-1.8";
}
```

The file loads into QGIS 3.28.3 insofar as the geometry is correctly parsed:

[QGIS 3.28.3 export of file geometry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FY68R.png)

though the CRS is not recognised. I suspect this is due to the bundled version of GDAL/OGR in QGIS being somewhat old at 3.3.2 - a separate install of GDAL 3.5.1 appears to correctly recognise it.
Any attempt to also load data variables quickly leads to a crash exit unfortunately.

Panoply doesn't seem to recognise any georeferencing in the file at all:

[Panoply not showing any georeferenced variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjdfN.png)

though it is happy to produce line plots for the time series data within:

[Plot of average speed time series for an unspecified segment ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8XvY.png)

So my question is, what else am I missing for this file to be recognised as a CF-1.8 compliant time series using discrete sampling geometries expressed as lines?
I have got this far largely from reverse-engineering the checks done by [cf-checker](https://github.com/cedadev/cf-checker)

Here is a link to a small example output file that holds all the geometry I mention but just one slice of the time series:

[Example file](https://tempfile.io/en/0T3h0DQ7w8ctxOT/file)

The script I used to generate this file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import netCDF4 as nc
import cfgeom as cf

my_nc_file = nc.Dataset("small_test.nc", "w", format="NETCDF4")
my_nc_file.Conventions = 'CF-1.8'
my_nc_file.title = 'Road flow rate metrics'
my_nc_file.history = '2023-02-28 09:00:00'
my_nc_file.featureType = 'timeSeries'

source_df = gpd.read_file('small_output.gpkg').sort_values(by=['roadSegmentId','localTzDateTime'])

ts_entries = source_df.localTzDateTime.drop_duplicates()
ts_count = len(ts_entries)

segment_entries = source_df.roadSegmentId.drop_duplicates()
segment_count = len(segment_entries)

dim_ts = my_nc_file.createDimension('ts', ts_count)

g = source_df[source_df.localTzDateTime == ts_entries.iloc[0]].geometry
lines = cf.read_shapely(g.tolist())
lines.to_netcdf(my_nc_file, use_vlen=False)

from pyproj import CRS
crs = CRS("EPSG:4326")
crs_cf = crs.to_cf()

my_nc_file.createVariable('grid_mapping','u1')
my_nc_file.variables['grid_mapping'].setncatts(crs_cf)
my_nc_file.variables['grid_mapping'].horizontal_datum_name = 'World Geodetic System 1984 ensemble'
my_nc_file.variables['geometry_container'].grid_mapping = 'grid_mapping'

times = my_nc_file.createVariable('ts','u8',('ts',))

segments = my_nc_file.createVariable('segment','u8',('instance',))
segments.cf_role = 'timeseries_id'

osm_id = my_nc_file.createVariable('osm_id','u8',('instance',))
road_name = my_nc_file.createVariable('road_name',str,('instance',))
average_speed = my_nc_file.createVariable('avg_speed','f4',('instance','ts',))
vehicle_density = my_nc_file.createVariable('vehicle_density','u1',('instance','ts',))
stationary = my_nc_file.createVariable('stationary','f4',('instance','ts',))
hard_brake = my_nc_file.createVariable('hard_brake','u1',('instance','ts',))
hard_accel = my_nc_file.createVariable('hard_accel','u1',('instance','ts',))

times[:] = (pd.to_datetime(ts_entries) - pd.Timestamp('1970-01-01')) // pd.Timedelta('1s')
segments[:] = segment_entries
average_speed[:] = source_df.averageSpeed.to_numpy().reshape(segment_count,ts_count)
vehicle_density[:] = source_df.vehicleDensity.to_numpy().reshape(segment_count,ts_count)
stationary[:] = source_df.stationary.astype('float').to_numpy().reshape(segment_count,ts_count)
hard_brake[:] = source_df.hardBrake.to_numpy().reshape(segment_count,ts_count)
hard_accel[:] = source_df.hardAcceleration.to_numpy().reshape(segment_count,ts_count)
osm_id[:] = source_df[['roadSegmentId','osmId']].drop_duplicates()['osmId']
road_name[:] = source_df[['roadSegmentId','roadSegmentName']].drop_duplicates()['roadSegmentName'].fillna('').to_numpy()

my_nc_file.variables['ts'].standard_name = 'time'
my_nc_file.variables['ts'].units = 'seconds since 1970-1-1 0:0:0'
my_nc_file.variables['ts'].calendar = 'standard'

my_nc_file.variables['segment'].long_name = 'segment ID'
my_nc_file.variables['segment'].units = '1'
my_nc_file.variables['segment'].geometry = 'geometry_container'
my_nc_file.variables['segment'].grid_mapping = 'grid_mapping'

my_nc_file.variables['avg_speed'].long_name = 'Arithmetic mean of observed speeds over time period'
my_nc_file.variables['avg_speed'].units = 'mph'
my_nc_file.variables['avg_speed'].geometry = 'geometry_container'
my_nc_file.variables['avg_speed'].grid_mapping = 'grid_mapping'
my_nc_file.variables['avg_speed'].coordinates = 'segment ts'

my_nc_file.variables['vehicle_density'].long_name = 'Count of observed vehicles'
my_nc_file.variables['vehicle_density'].units = "1"
my_nc_file.variables['vehicle_density'].geometry = 'geometry_container'
my_nc_file.variables['vehicle_density'].grid_mapping = 'grid_mapping'
my_nc_file.variables['vehicle_density'].coordinates = 'segment ts'

my_nc_file.variables['stationary'].long_name = 'Average stationary time per vehicle'
my_nc_file.variables['stationary'].units = "s"
my_nc_file.variables['stationary'].geometry = 'geometry_container'
my_nc_file.variables['stationary'].grid_mapping = 'grid_mapping'
my_nc_file.variables['stationary'].coordinates = 'segment ts'

my_nc_file.variables['hard_brake'].long_name = 'Count of hard braking events'
my_nc_file.variables['hard_brake'].units = "1"
my_nc_file.variables['hard_brake'].geometry = 'geometry_container'
my_nc_file.variables['hard_brake'].grid_mapping = 'grid_mapping'
my_nc_file.variables['hard_brake'].coordinates = 'segment ts'

my_nc_file.variables['hard_accel'].long_name = 'Count of hard acceleration events'
my_nc_file.variables['hard_accel'].units = "1"
my_nc_file.variables['hard_accel'].geometry = 'geometry_container'
my_nc_file.variables['hard_accel'].grid_mapping = 'grid_mapping'
my_nc_file.variables['hard_accel'].coordinates = 'segment ts'

my_nc_file.variables['osm_id'].long_name = 'OpenStreetMap ID associated with segment'
my_nc_file.variables['osm_id'].units = '1'
my_nc_file.variables['osm_id'].geometry = 'geometry_container'
my_nc_file.variables['osm_id'].grid_mapping = 'grid_mapping'

my_nc_file.variables['road_name'].long_name = 'Road name for segment drawn from OSM'
my_nc_file.variables['road_name'].units = '1'
my_nc_file.variables['road_name'].geometry = 'geometry_container'
my_nc_file.variables['road_name'].grid_mapping = 'grid_mapping'

my_nc_file.variables['x'].standard_name = 'longitude'
my_nc_file.variables['x'].units = 'degrees_east'

my_nc_file.variables['y'].standard_name = 'latitude'
my_nc_file.variables['y'].units = 'degrees_north'

my_nc_file.variables['node_count'].units = '1'

my_nc_file.close()
```

And the source GPKG file referenced in the code:

[Source GPKG file](https://tempfile.io/en/na8cv0TcFpmcILD/file)

Comment: i have the same problem. as the question is 7 months old i assume the issue was solved already but maybe this comment will help someone in the future. 
you can get around it by using `xarray`'s `to_netcdf()`. this will be recognized as geo referenced by gdal/qgis (Version  3.32.3). as for working with pythons `netCDF4` or R's `ncdf4` i'd like an answer as well